# color state list equivalent for images

Tags: android, gallery

I'm using a galery and have used `getColorStateList` to display texts in a different color when they are selected, declaring an xml like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/yellow"></item>

    <item android:state_selected="false" android:color="@color/white"></item>

    <item android:color="#FFFFFF"></item>
</selector>
```

I need to do something quite similar with images : 
I want display a different image when it's selected in the gallery.

do anyone knows how to do so ?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think use a selector for imageview just like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/your_image" />


    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/your_image" />
    <!--normal state-->
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_image" />
```

place all your image in drawable folder